# Regular expression for remove link

Tags: regex, hyperlink

I need to clean all links in long string. Eg:

```
http://www.example.com

http://example.com

www.example.net

youtube.com/user/123456

facebook.com/example

sub.domain.com
```

I want remove all link and choosing this code but not working all links.

```
(?>http?://|ww\w\.).+?(?=\s)
```

How to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular Expression:

```
(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)
```

Example Execution: http://regexr.com?38bj4

Reference: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149

Comment: This is quite robust! Was surprised at how many different cases it caught, thank you!

Comment: fails, if a link contains a port-definition (i.e. `https://domain.tld:8443/`

Answer (score 1):

Same as Matthew wrote but would get rid of that space in the last bracket - then it won't catch the text after the link. So it would be like this:

```
(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)
```

PS. Sorry Matthew - I cannot yet comment. But I've created the account to thank you for your reply - it solved my issue as well :)